# How do i set my animation according to my timer in unity?

Tags: c#, animation, timer, unity-game-engine

Basically i have a class that draws out my car animation according to values from a sqlite database and a timer. here is the code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.IO;
 using System;
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

     public class NodeData
     {
         public int time;

         public int posX;
         public int posY;
         public int posZ;
         public float temp;

     }

     public class VehicleData
     {
         public VehicleData()
         {
             time = new List<float>();
             posX = new List<float>();
         }

         public List<float> time;
         public List<float> posX;
     }

     private int maxLength = 700;//10500/15;
     private int maxWidth = 13;//225/15;//(int) Math.Ceiling(200.0f/15.0f)+1;
     private int maxHeight = 15;//150/15;
     private int maxTime = 61;
     public GameObject MainHoldingobj;
     public Texture crosshair;
     private Main getfromMain;
     private float dividedValue; 

     float minTemp = 100;
     float maxTemp;

     List<VehicleData> vehicleData;
     float[][,,] data;
     int[,,] lastTimeData;

     Material mat;
     public Material transMat;

     GameObject[,,] cubes;
     ParticleSystem.Particle[,,] tempPart = new ParticleSystem.Particle[50,10,40];
     //NodeData[][,,] testYo =  new NodeData[maxLength/gridBoxSize,maxHeight/gridBoxSize,maxWidth/gridBoxSize];
     public float oneSecTimer;
     public float timer;

     [Range(0,1)]
     public float alphaValue;
     public float carTransparency = 0.5f;
     public bool lockTime = true;
     public bool showAll = true;
     public bool showCar = true;
     public GameObject RcCube;
     Vector3 vehicleSize = new Vector3(450/100,135/66,165/80);
     int[] carCounter;
     float[] carPosCounter;
     SqliteDatabase sqlDB;
     DataTable Heatmapdt;
     DataTable abmdt;
     string query = "";

     public enum dataType
     {
         air,
         ground,
         building
     }

     public float getDataTypeAlpha(dataType type)
     {
         //return transparency based on type range 0-1
         switch (type)
         {
         case dataType.air :
             return 0.1f;
             break;
         case dataType.ground :
             return 1.0f;
             break;
         case dataType.building :
             return 0.5f;
             break;
             // no such type
         default:
             return 0.0f;

         }
     }


     void readVehicleData ()
     {
         int id;
         float tempX;
         float tempTime;

         for (int i = 0; i < abmdt.Rows.Count; i++) {

             id = int.Parse(abmdt[i]["ID"].ToString());

             if(id > vehicleData.Count-1)
             {
                 VehicleData tempData = new VehicleData();
                 tempX = (float.Parse(abmdt[i]["PosX"].ToString()));
                 tempTime = float.Parse(abmdt[i]["Time"].ToString());

                 tempData.time.Add(tempTime/1000);
                 tempData.posX.Add(tempX*100.0f/15.0f);
                 vehicleData.Add(tempData);
             }
             else{
                 vehicleData[int.Parse(abmdt[i]["ID"].ToString ())].time.Add(float.Parse(abmdt[i]["Time"].ToString())/1000);
                 vehicleData[int.Parse(abmdt[i]["ID"].ToString ())].posX.Add((float.Parse(abmdt[i]["PosX"].ToString()))*100.0f/15.0f);
             }


         }
         carCounter = new int[vehicleData.Count];
         carPosCounter = new float[vehicleData.Count];

         for (int i=0; i<vehicleData.Count; i++) {
             carCounter[i] = -1;        
             carPosCounter[i] = 0;
         }
         //    Debug.Log (maxX + " " + maxY + " " + maxZ + " " + maxTemp + " " + maxTime);

     }


     void readStreamLineData ()
     {
         var reader = new StreamReader (File.OpenRead ("ccs_data2/heatmap_output_all_vehicles_a.csv")); //heatmap_output_all_one_cm

         int maxX = 0, maxY=0, maxZ =0; 
         float maxTemp = 0, maxTime = 0;
         while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
         {
             NodeData tempData = new NodeData();

             var line = reader.ReadLine ();
             var values = line.Split (',');

             if (values.Length == 5) 
             {
                 if (int.TryParse (values [0], out tempData.time)

                     && int.TryParse (values [1], out tempData.posX)
                     && int.TryParse (values [2], out tempData.posY)
                     && int.TryParse (values [3], out tempData.posZ)

                     && float.TryParse (values [4], NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempData.temp)) 
                 {

                     //                    if(tempData.posX > maxX)
                     //                        maxX =tempData.posX;
                     //
                     //                    if(tempData.posY > maxY)
                     //                        maxY =tempData.posY;
                     //
                     //                    if(tempData.posZ > maxZ)
                     //                        maxZ =tempData.posZ;
                     //
                     //                    if(tempData.temp > maxTemp)
                     //                        maxTemp =tempData.temp;
                     //
                     //                    if(tempData.time > maxTime)
                     //                        maxTime =tempData.time;
                     //
                     //                    if(tempData.posX > maxLength-1)
                     //                        Debug.Log("Alert x");
                     //                    else if(tempData.posY > maxHeight-1)
                     //                        Debug.Log("Alert y");
                     //                    else if(tempData.posZ > maxWidth-1)
                     //                        Debug.Log("Alert z");
                     //                    else if(tempData.time/1000 > maxTime-1)
                     //                        Debug.Log("Alert time");

                     data[tempData.time/1000][tempData.posX,tempData.posY,tempData.posZ] = tempData.temp;

                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     continue;    
                 }
             }
         }

         //    Debug.Log (maxX + " " + maxY + " " + maxZ + " " + maxTemp + " " + maxTime);


     }








     void findMinMax()
     {
         for(int t =0;t<maxTime;t++)
         {
             for(int x =0;x<maxLength;x++)
             {
                 for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
                 {
                     for(int z =0;z<maxWidth;z++)
                     {
                         if(data[t][x,y,z] < minTemp && data[t][x,y,z] !=0)
                             minTemp = data[t][x,y,z];

                         if(data[t][x,y,z] > maxTemp && data[t][x,y,z] <100)
                         {
                             //Debug.Log ("maxTemp: + " + maxTemp + "Data: " + data[t][x,y,z]);
                             maxTemp = data[t][x,y,z];
                             //Debug.Log ("maxTemp2: + " + maxTemp + "Data2: " + data[t][x,y,z]);

                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         //dividedValue = (int)((maxTemp - minTemp)/0.7f);
         dividedValue = ((maxTemp - minTemp)/0.7f);
     }

     void createCubes()
     {
         for(int x =0;x<50;x++)
         {
             for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
             {
                 for(int z =10;z<30;z++)
                 {
                     cubes[x,y,z] = new GameObject();
                     cubes[x,y,z] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                     cubes[x,y,z].transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                     cubes[x,y,z].GetComponent<Renderer>().material= new Material(transMat);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     void createParticles()
     {
         for(int x =0;x<50;x++)
         {
             for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
             {
                 for(int z =10;z<30;z++)
                 {
                     tempPart[x,y,z].position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     void initializeData()
     {
         vehicleData = new List<VehicleData> ();

         cubes = new GameObject[maxLength, maxHeight, maxWidth];
         data =  new float[maxTime][,,];
         lastTimeData = new int[maxLength,maxHeight,maxWidth];
         for (int i = 0; i < maxTime; i++)
             data[i] = new float[maxLength,maxHeight,maxWidth];

         for(int t =0;t<maxTime;t++)
         {
             for(int x =0;x<maxLength;x++)
             {
                 for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
                 {
                     for(int z =0;z<maxWidth;z++)
                     {
                         data[t][x,y,z] = 0;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         //last data time
         for (int x =0; x<maxLength; x++) 
         {
             for (int y =0; y<maxHeight; y++) 
             {
                 for (int z =0; z<maxWidth; z++) 
                 {
                     lastTimeData[x,y,z] = 0;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         //tt = mCam.GetComponent<testingtime> ();
         getfromMain = MainHoldingobj.GetComponent<Main> ();

         sqlDB = new SqliteDatabase("Test01");
         query = "SELECT * FROM Heatmap WHERE Time ="+((int)(detailedTimer * 1000));
         Heatmapdt = sqlDB.ExecuteQuery(query);
         string query2 = "SELECT * FROM abm WHERE ID = 0";
         abmdt = sqlDB.ExecuteQuery (query2);



         initializeData();
         readStreamLineData();
         readVehicleData ();
         //createCubes();
         //createParticles();
         findMinMax();




     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

         //        for(int x =0;x<50;x++)
         //        {
         //            for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
         //            {
         //                for(int z =10;z<30;z++)
         //                {
         //                    cubes[x,y,z].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = returnColour((int)timer,x,y,z);
         //                }
         //            }
         //        }
         //
         //        for(int x =0;x<50;x++)
         //        {
         //            for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
         //            {
         //                for(int z =10;z<30;z++)
         //                {
         //                    tempPart[x,y,z].color = returnColour((int)timer,x,y,z);
         //                }
         //            }
         //        }


         //        if(!showAll)
         //        {
         //            for(int x =0;x<maxLength;x++)
         //            {
         //                for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
         //                {
         //                    for(int z =0;z<maxWidth;z++)
         //                    {
         //                        if( data[(int)timer][x,y,z] !=0)
         //                        {
         //                            cubes[x,y,z].SetActive(true);
         //                        }
         //                        else
         //                        {
         //                            cubes[x,y,z].SetActive(false);
         //                        }
         //                    }
         //                }
         //            }
         //        }
     }

     public float detailedTimer = 0;
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if(!lockTime)
         {


             if(timer+1 >maxTime)
             {
                 timer = 0;
                 detailedTimer = 0;

                 for(int i=0; i< vehicleData.Count;i++)
                 {    carCounter[i] = -1;
                     carPosCounter[i] = 0; 
                 }
             }

             if(oneSecTimer <1)
                 oneSecTimer +=Time.fixedDeltaTime;
             else
             {
                 oneSecTimer = 0;
                 //timer ++;
             }
         //    detailedTimer = (float)tt.playtime;
             detailedTimer = getfromMain.timer;
              timer = getfromMain.timer;
             //detailedTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

             //update each car
                 for(int i=0; i< vehicleData.Count;i++)
             {
                 if(carCounter[i]+1 < vehicleData[i].time.Count)
                 {
                     if(getfromMain.timer < vehicleData[i].time[carCounter[i]+1])
                     {
                         if(carCounter[i] != -1)
                         {
                             //interpolation so that it will move smoothly?
                             //carPosCounter[i] += 
                             carPosCounter[i] = 0; 
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         carCounter[i]++;

                         //check if it has exceeded a lot? put some space
                         carPosCounter[i] = 0; 
                     }
                 }
             }


         }

         //Debug.Log (timer);
     }




     void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {

         //
         //        for(int x =0;x<maxLength;x++)
         //        {
         //            for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
         //            {
         //                for(int z =0;z<maxWidth;z++)
         //                {
         //
         //                        if(showAll)
         //                        {
         //                            Gizmos.color = returnColour((int)timer,x,y,z);
         //                            Gizmos.DrawCube(new Vector3(x,y,z), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
         //                        }
         //                        else
         //                        {
         //                            if( data[(int)timer][x,y,z] !=0)
         //                            {
         //                                Gizmos.color = returnColour((int)timer,x,y,z);
         //                                Gizmos.DrawCube(new Vector3(x,y,z), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
         //                            }
         //                        }
         //                    
         //                }
         //            }
         //        }

         //        Gizmos.color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 155);
         //
         //        Gizmos.DrawCube(new Vector3(0,10,0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
         //        Debug.Log ("hi");
     }


     void OnPostRender()
     {
         if (!mat) 
         {
             mat = new Material ("Shader \"Lines/Colored Blended\" {" +
                                 "SubShader {" +
                                 "    Tags { \"Queue\" = \"Transparent\" }" +
                                 " Pass { " +
                                 "    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha " +
                                 //"    Blend One One " +
                                 "    ZWrite Off Cull Off Fog { Mode Off } " +
                                 "    BindChannels {" +
                                 "      Bind \"vertex\", vertex Bind \"color\", color }" +
                                 "} } }");
             //            mat = new Material(shader);
             mat.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
             mat.shader.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
         }

         //draw cubes
         GL.PushMatrix ();
         mat.SetPass (0);
 //        GL.Begin (GL.QUADS);
 //        for(int x =0;x<maxLength;x++)
 //        {
 //            for(int y =0;y<maxHeight;y++)
 //            {
 //                for(int z =0;z<maxWidth;z++)
 //                {
 //                    if(showAll)
 //                    {
 //                        GL.Color( returnColour((int)timer,x,y,z));
 //                        drawCube(x,y,z,1.0f);
 //                    }
 //                    
 //                    else
 //                    {
 //                        if(data[(int)timer][x,y,z] !=0)
 //                        {
 //                            GL.Color( returnColour((int)timer,x,y,z));
 //                            drawCube(x,y,z,1.0f);
 //                        }
 //                    }
 //                    
 //                    
 //                }
 //            }
 //        }
 //        GL.End ();
         GL.PopMatrix ();

         //draw car
         GL.PushMatrix ();
         mat.SetPass (0);
         GL.Begin (GL.QUADS);




         int tempi = 0;



         for(int i =0;i<vehicleData.Count;i++)
         {
         //    if(vehicleData[i].time[] < getfromMain.timer)
     //            continue;
         //    else 
     //            tempi = i;



             if(showCar)
             {
                 if((carCounter[i] != -1) && (carCounter[i] < (vehicleData[i].time.Count-1)) )//&& vehicleData[i].time[carCounter[i]] < maxTime
                 {
                     GL.Color(new Color(1,0,0,carTransparency));
                     drawCar(vehicleData[i].posX[carCounter[i]]+carPosCounter[i]);
                     Vector3 mampos = new Vector3(0,1.5f,1.5f);
                     mampos.x = (vehicleData[i].posX[carCounter[i]]+carPosCounter[i])+1.5f;
                     RcCube.transform.position = mampos;


                 }
             }
         }

         GL.End ();
         GL.PopMatrix ();
     }

     void drawCube(int x,int y,int z, float size)
     {
         size = size/2;
         //GL.Color( returnColour((int)timer,0,0,0));
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y + size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y + size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y + size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y + size, z - size);

         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y - size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y - size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y - size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y - size, z - size);

         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y + size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y - size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y - size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y + size, z - size);

         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y + size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y - size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y - size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y + size, z - size);

         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y + size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y + size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y - size, z + size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y - size, z + size);

         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y + size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y + size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x - size,y - size, z - size);
         GL.Vertex3(x + size,y - size, z - size);

     }

     void drawCar(float x)
     {
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,vehicleSize.y, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,vehicleSize.y, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,vehicleSize.y, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,vehicleSize.y, 1);

         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,0, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,0, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,0, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,0, 1);

         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,vehicleSize.y, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,0, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,0, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,vehicleSize.y, 1);

         GL.Vertex3(x,vehicleSize.y, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,0, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,0, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x,vehicleSize.y, 1);

         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,vehicleSize.y, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,vehicleSize.y, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x,0, vehicleSize.z);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,0, vehicleSize.z);

         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,vehicleSize.y, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x,vehicleSize.y, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x,0, 1);
         GL.Vertex3(x + vehicleSize.x,0, 1);

     }








     Color returnColour(int t,int x,int y,int z)
     {

         if ((t + 1) < maxTime) {
             float temp = 0;
             temp = data [t] [x, y, z];

             if (temp != 0)
                 lastTimeData [x, y, z] = t;
             else
                 temp = data [lastTimeData [x, y, z]] [x, y, z];

             float temp2 = 0;
             if (data [t + 1] [x, y, z] != 0)
                 temp2 = data [t + 1] [x, y, z];
             else
                 temp2 = data [lastTimeData [x, y, z]] [x, y, z];


             //        float value = maxTemp - temp;
             //        float value2 = maxTemp - temp2;
             //
             //        Color lerping =Color.Lerp(HSBColor.ToColor(new HSBColor(value/dividedValue,1.0f,1.0f,alphaValue)),HSBColor.ToColor(new HSBColor(value2/dividedValue,1.0f,1.0f,alphaValue)),oneSecTimer);
             //        if (temp < 100)
             //                        return lerping;
             //                else
             //            //return new Color(1,1,1,1);
             //                        return HSBColor.ToColor (new HSBColor (1, 1.0f, 1.0f, alphaValue));//full spectrum

             //    temp = data[x,y,z].temp[id];
             float value = maxTemp - temp;

             Color lerping = HSBColor.ToColor (new HSBColor (value / dividedValue, 1.0f, 1.0f, alphaValue));
             return lerping;

             //        float value = temp/(maxTemp - temp);
             //        if (temp < 50)
             //            return HSBColor.ToColor (new HSBColor (value * 0.7f, 1.0f, 0.5f));
             //        else
             //            return new Color(1,0,0,1);

             //        if(temp > 50)
             //            return new Color(1,0,0,0.5f); //red
             //        else if(temp > 45)
             //            return new Color(1,0.5f,0,0.5f); //
             //        else if(temp > 40)
             //            return new Color(0,1,0,0.5f); //green
             //        else if(temp > 35)
             //            return new Color(0,1,0.5f,0.5f); //
             //        else
             //            return new Color(0,0,1,0.5f); //blue

         } else
             return new Color (0, 0, 1, 0.5f);
     }


 }
```

The code is fairly messy and have alot of unused stuff lying around. The main classes you need to look at are VehicleData,ReadVehicleData,Start,fixedupdate and onpostrender.

So the problem is that whenever i change the value of detailedtimer, the animation just stops there I want to be able to control the animation with the value of detailedtimer but to do that i need to know the values of carcounter[i] and vehicledta[i] during that time. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: man, I don't think I understand what's your problem and I doubt anyone will unless you clean up your code and post only the relevant stuff.